# c++ fmt converting multiple numbers into an ip format

Tags: c++, fmt

Im trying convert numbers into an ip format

e.g 127.0.0.1

my code

```
fmt::format("{0}", num1, num2, num3, num4)
```

i didn't expect this to work but i tried it anyways

Comment: `fmt::format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", num1, num2, num3, num4)` is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

You just combine them in the format string:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::cout << fmt::format("{}.{}.{}.{}\n", 127, 0, 0, 1); 
}
```